# CONCAT within GROUP_CONCAT - How to remove duplicate result

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

`CONCAT` within `GROUP_CONCAT`, what is wrong with following mysql code ? Please see SQL Fiddle, full code is there.

Let me explain, I have 5 table

**cls** -   List of Classes

**sec** -   List of Sections

**fee** -   List of Fee

**cls_sec** - List of section assigned to each class

**cls_fee** - List of fee assigned to each section

Table `cls` - lists of Class

```
id  |   ttl
===========
1   |   One
2   |   Two
3   |   Three
```

Table `sec` - lists of section

```
id  |   ttl
===========
1   |   A
2   |   B
```

Table `cls_sec` - lists of each section assigned to Class

```
id  |   c_id|   s_id    
=====================
1   |   1   |   1
2   |   1   |   2
3   |   2   |   1
```

Table `fee` - lists of fee category

```
id  |   ttl
===========
1   |   Annual
2   |   Monthly
3   |   Library
```

Table `cls_fee` - lists of each fee and amount assigned to Class

```
id  |   c_id|   s_id|   f_id|   fee 
=====================================
1   |   1   |   1   |   1   |    2000
2   |   1   |   1   |   2   |    500
3   |   1   |   2   |   1   |    3000
4   |   1   |   2   |   2   |    400
5   |   2   |   1   |   1   |    4500
6   |   2   |   1   |   2   |    450
7   |   3   |   0   |   1   |    5000
8   |   3   |   0   |   2   |    600
9   |   3   |   0   |   3   |    300
```

Here I am trying to include all relation in one `GROUP_CONCAT` Result

**My current output (Class name and section name is fetched repetitively according to fee )**

```
//Class Name - Section Name (if exist) - fee, Class Name - Section Name (if exist) - fee ..

3.Three.Library->300, 3.Three.Monthly->600, 3.Three.Annual->5000, 
2.Two-A.Monthly->450, 2.Two-A.Annual->4500, 1.One-A.Monthly->500, 
1.One-A.Annual->2000, 1.One-B.Monthly->400, 1.One-B.Annual->3000
```

**with following code**

```
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('\r\n',cls.id,'.',cls.ttl,
       COALESCE(CONCAT('-',sec.ttl),''),COALESCE(CONCAT('.',fee.ttl,'->',cls_fee.fee))) 
       ORDER BY sec.id) AS cls
```

**But what I want (remove duplication class and section)**

```
//Class Name - Section Name (if exists) - fee, fee

3.Three.Library->300,Monthly->600,Annual->5000, 
2.Two-A.Monthly->450,Annual->4500, 
1.One-A.Monthly->500,Annual->2000,
1.One-B.Monthly->400,Annual->3000
```

So I add `CONCAT` within nested `CONCAT`

```
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('\r\n',cls.id,'.',cls.ttl,
      COALESCE(CONCAT('-',sec.ttl,COALESCE(CONCAT('.',fee.ttl,'->',cls_fee.fee))), '')) 
      ORDER BY sec.id) AS cls
```

**and got output, but it doesn't fetch as expected, also missing some fee**

```
3.Three,
2.Two-A.Monthly->450, 2.Two-A.Annual->4500, 
1.One-A.Monthly->500, 1.One-A.Annual->2000, 
1.One-B.Monthly->400, 1.One-B.Annual->3000
```

**MySQL CODE**

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('\r\n',cls.id,'.',cls.ttl,
      COALESCE(CONCAT('-',sec.ttl),''),COALESCE(CONCAT('.',fee.ttl,'->',cls_fee.fee))) 
      ORDER BY sec.id) AS cls
FROM
  cls
LEFT JOIN
  cls_sec ON cls_sec.cls = cls.id
LEFT JOIN
  sec ON sec.id = cls_sec.sec
LEFT JOIN
  cls_fee ON cls_fee.c_id = cls.id
LEFT JOIN
  fee ON fee.id = cls_fee.f_id
WHERE
  CASE WHEN cls_fee.s_id != 0 THEN cls_fee.s_id = sec.id ELSE cls.id END
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d2539/6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a subquery to write `GROUP_CONCAT` from detail by  `cls.id, cls.ttl` then do `GROUP_CONCAT` again in the main query.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Id,'.',ttl,'.',flag,cls)  ORDER BY Id desc,flag) result
FROM (
  SELECT
     cls.id,
     cls.ttl,
     COALESCE(CONCAT('-',sec.ttl),'') flag,
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
                COALESCE(CONCAT('.',fee.ttl,'->',cls_fee.fee))) 
                ORDER BY sec.id) AS cls
  FROM
    cls
  LEFT JOIN
    cls_sec ON cls_sec.cls = cls.id
  LEFT JOIN
    sec ON sec.id = cls_sec.sec
  LEFT JOIN
    cls_fee ON cls_fee.c_id = cls.id
  LEFT JOIN
    fee ON fee.id = cls_fee.f_id
  WHERE
    CASE WHEN cls_fee.s_id != 0 THEN cls_fee.s_id = sec.id ELSE cls.id END
  GROUP BY 
     cls.id,
     cls.ttl,
     COALESCE(CONCAT('-',sec.ttl),'')
)t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d2539/23/0)**:

```
|                                                                                                                                                        result |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 3.Three..Library->300,.Monthly->600,.Annual->5000,2.Two.-A.Monthly->450,.Annual->4500,1.One.-A.Monthly->500,.Annual->2000,1.One.-B.Monthly->400,.Annual->3000 |
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks dude !!